# calling api from service within angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to call an api from within my factory method using angularjs.

But it never calls the api on the server side which is written in express.

any ideas?

```
angular.module('ecoProject')
 .factory('UserService', function($http){
+
+        var loginUser = function() {
+            $http({ method: 'POST',
+                url: '/api/getUserDetails',
+                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
+            }).
+                success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
+                    return data;
+
+                }).
+                error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
+                    //hits this when unauthorized.
+                    var invalid = true;
+                });
+        };
+
+    return {
+        getUsername: function() {
+            console.log(loginUser);
+            return "success";
+        }
+    };
+});
```

I have implemented the following code using promises now and it returns data but not what i expect just a load of html

```
angular.module('ecoProject')
.service('UserService', function ($http, $q) {
var deferred = $q.defer();

$http.get('api/user').then(function(data){
    deferred.resolve(data);

});

this.getUsername = function() {
         return deferred.promise;
     }
```

});

Comment: It looks like you don't call loginUser anywhere.

Comment: Setup a plunker with your current so we can help faster

Comment: I have implemented another method but have changed the factory to service and it works now.

Comment: got it working now the api call had to be moved higher in the file so that the following code did not override app.get('*', ensureAuthenticated, function(req,res, next)
{
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/app/index.html');
});